# how to put if else condition in LIMIT mysql

Tags: mysql, if-statement, limit

here is my query

```
$where_or = " 
                AND
                    content_status = 'Active'
                AND
                    content_post_status = 'published'
                AND
                    deleted = 0
                AND
                    content_type = '$type'
                ORDER BY content_created_at DESC ";

        $select = "content_id, content_title, content_short_description, content_url, content_created_at";

        $query = $this->db->query("
                (
                    SELECT $select
                    FROM tbl_content
                    WHERE 
                    content_category_id = 54
                    $where_or
                    LIMIT 3
                )
                UNION ALL 
                (
                    SELECT $select
                    FROM tbl_content
                    WHERE 
                    content_category_id = 55
                    $where_or
                    LIMIT 2
                )
                UNION ALL 
                (
                    SELECT $select
                    FROM tbl_content
                    WHERE 
                    content_category_id = 56
                    $where_or
                    LIMIT 2
                )
                UNION ALL 
                (
                    SELECT $select
                    FROM tbl_content
                    WHERE 
                    content_category_id = 57
                    $where_or
                    LIMIT 1
                )
                UNION ALL 
                (
                    SELECT $select
                    FROM tbl_content
                    WHERE 
                    content_category_id = 58
                    $where_or
                    LIMIT 1
                )
                UNION ALL 
                (
                    SELECT $select
                    FROM tbl_content
                    WHERE 
                    content_category_id = 60
                    $where_or
                    LIMIT 1
                )
                UNION ALL 
                (
                    SELECT $select
                    FROM tbl_content
                    WHERE 
                    content_category_id = 61
                    $where_or
                    LIMIT 1
                )
                UNION ALL 
                (
                    SELECT $select
                    FROM tbl_content
                    WHERE 
                    content_category_id = 118
                    $where_or
                    if content_type = 'article'
                    begin 
                        LIMIT 10
                    end
                )   
        ");
```

You can see in last UNION i want to put limit on if condition ..but its giving me error...how can i do that...please help..

Comment: That... makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with MySQL, at least not the way you are trying to. If you think about it 
this:

```
if content_type = 'article'
begin 
   LIMIT 10
end
```

doesn't make sense. LIMIT is applied to a set not a single record. If what you wrote were valid SQL and your data contained both content that was true for content_type = 'article' and some that was false. What would you expect to happen?

Comment: I don't even wan't to know why you are doing this, glad you found a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to rank records and then add WHERE condtition to filter records by `content_category_id` and its rank. In this case you will avoid using multiple SELECT...FROM queries.

Comment: i have two tables tbl_cats and tbl_content... tbl_content has cat_id ..i have to get record on the basis of cat_id ...like cat_id = 1 record limit will be 3 and so on... there's other ways of doing this but it seems to me most easy of doing it...